# How to save each steps of quicksort in matrix in java?

Tags: java, matrix, quicksort

I have trouble saving each step of sorting quickstep. I wrote this but its not printing anything...
I want to make javafx application with feature that i can push next button and it makes one step and back button which goes step back. So i will run the whole quicksort and save all the iterations to matrix and later i will be showing each column of the matrix bz clicking next and back. So i wanted to strat from beginning but im stuck in saving the steps.

Edit:
P.S. I know should print the matrix each step and i dont want that, i will add some condition later.

```
public class QS {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] x = { 9, 2, 4, 7, 3, 7, 10 };
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));

        final int [] [] test  = {
            {1,2,3},
            {4,5,6},
            {7,8,9}
        };

        //for (int p = 0; p < test.length; p++){
        //    for (int k = 0; k < test[p].length; k++){
        //        System.out.print(test[p][k] + " ");
        //    }
        //    System.out.println();
        //}

        int low = 0;
        int high = x.length - 1;
        quickSort(x, low, high);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));
        int [] [] save = new int [9] [x.length];
    }

    public static void quickSort(int[] arr, int low, int high) {
        if (arr == null || arr.length == 0)
            return;

        if (low >= high)
            return;

        // pick the pivot
        int middle = low + (high - low) / 2;
        int pivot = arr[middle];

        // make left < pivot and right > pivot
        int i = low, j = high;
        while (i <= j) {
            while (arr[i] < pivot)
                i++;

            while (arr[j] > pivot)
                j--;

            if (i <= j) {
                int temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }

        int[][] save = new int[9][arr.length];
        int index = 0;
        // recursively sort two sub parts
        if (low < j)
            quickSort(arr, low, j);

        for (int h=0; h>arr.length+1; h++){
            save [index] [h] = arr [h];
            index++;

            for (int e = 0; e < save.length; e++) {
                for (int f = 0; f < save[e].length; f++) {
                    System.out.print(save[e][f] + " ");
                }

                System.out.println();
            }
        }

        if (high > i)
            quickSort(arr, i, high);

        for (int h=0; h>arr.length+1; h++){
            save [index] [h] = arr [h];
            index++;

            for (int e = 0; e < save.length; e++) {
                for (int f = 0; f < save[e].length; f++) {
                    System.out.print(save[e][f] + " ");
                }

                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ondra! Could you reduce your problem to a smaller example? Your question appears to be more about your specific code than programming constructs, libraries, or techniques, and Stackoverflow questions are most answerable when they're small and specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the for loops like this one:

```
for (int h=0; h>arr.length+1; h++){/*code*/}
```

Presumably, it should be a smaller-than sign:

```
for (int h=0; h<arr.length+1; h++){/*code*/}
```

Otherwise h is always bigger than arr.length+1, making the condition false and and the loop just stops there.